# How to find if substring is in a variable in awk

Tags: awk

i am using awk and need to find if a variable , in this case $24 contains the word 3:2- if so to print the line (for sed command)- the variable may include more letters or spaces or \n.......
for ex.

```
$24 == "3:2" {print "s/(inter = ).*/\\1\"" "3:2_pulldown" "\"/" >> NR  }
```

in my above line- it never find such a string although it exists.

can you help me with the command please??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for "3:2" **within** $24, then you want `$24 ~ /3:2/` or `index($24, "3:2") > 0`

Why are you using awk to generate a sed script?

**Update**

To pass a variable from the shell to awk, use the -v option:

```
val="3:2"  # or however you determine this value
awk -v v="$val" '$24 ~ v {print}'
```

Comment: i can't put this as it is in the condition- so how will i do that?$24 ~ /3:2/

Comment: the index worked properly!! thx i'm doing it cuze i have a table i want to go over line by line- according to each line i need to create a file- to replace some words in- with the word that appears in the table by using sed, does it answer your question??

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$24~/3:2/' file_name
```

this will serach for "3:2" in field 24